# How to convert .md to .Rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have downloaded an .md file from github ([here](https://gist.github.com/kantale/ff6179b97efc32153080097756280b7e)).
Is it possible to convert it to .Rmd?

Comment: Have you tried simply copy-pasting the raw `md` into a new `Rmd` document?

Comment: Just rename it to a .Rmd file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you just need to add a [YAML header](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/rmarkdown/rmarkdown_seminar_flat.html#yaml-header) to convert `.md` -> `.Rmd`.

First we `readLines` into an object. You may use the raw link directly, or alternatively `foo.md` if you have it already stored it in your working directory (WD) (`getwd()`).

Then we use `cat()` to print 1. YAML header and 2. append line-wise the `.md` content to the file. For 2. we use a `for` loop.

```
link <- 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kantale/ff6179b97efc32153080097756280b7e/raw/31e9522a80f16be610ac243be16f931493e48316/exams_BIOL_109_2020.md'
r <- readLines(link)
# r <- readLines('foo.md')

cat('---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
', file='foo.Rmd')  ## basic YAML header, may be customized
for (i in seq(r)) {cat(r[i], '\n', file='foo.Rmd', append=TRUE)}
```

This stores it a working `foo.Rmd` in your WD.

*Test it:*

```
rmarkdown::render('foo.Rmd')
```

`foo.html` should be produced in WD.

Answer (score 2):

R markdown is essentially a markdown file with an optional(!) header and code blocks. A md file is therefore a valid Rmd file by itself. You can ‘convert’ it by just adding a header manually, so you can control the output.

I have a simple package [here](https://github.com/minimumcosttohumanity/rmdmanip) that allows manipulation of rmd headers. I haven’t tested it on md files, but there’s a decent chance it will work.

Edit: tested it, I've updated the code after it failed, so should work now:

```
library(rmdmanip) #get it from link above, e.g. using devtools::install_github
read.rmd('filename.md') %>% put('title','your title') %>% dump('filename.Rmd)
```